# How to build project-wide UML diagram in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, uml, class-diagram

Trying to reverse-engineer existing project and it would be of great help to see how classes collaborate/depend on each other. Is there a way to build project-wide UML diagram (or class diagram of any kind) in IntelliJ IDEA using build-in functionallity or using some free plugin?

Comment: Note: Diagrams > Show Diagram feature is not available in the free Community Edition

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Right click on your `package` no matter which. Click `Diagrams` > `Show Diagram` (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+U). You will see your package in diagram editor.

Now:

- You can `expand` (E) or `collapse` (C) all nodes.
- You can show dependencies
- You can show many attributes of nodes (constructors, methods, properties...)
- **You can drag&drop other packages from project explorer**.

So, play with it a bit and I think you will achieve what you need.

This is how it could look like:
[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. I was confused how to expand nodes, now I see!

Comment: Does anyone know, how to add this feature to Android Studio?

Comment: i cannot see `Diagrams` option on right clicking my packages, i have idea 2016.1.1 CE

Comment: Does you project support maven? Does it contain pom.xml? Then right click on your module or inside opened pom.xml file and you should see `Diagrams` in the menu.

Comment: @Zavael This feature is only available for Ultimate edition.

Comment: I didn't see Expend and dependency?

Comment: How do you export this as an Image, i am getting an error: too large for export. I want to render this in gliffy in confluence. any clues?