# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate: how to build UML diagram for the whole project?

Tags: intellij-idea, uml

I'm getting started with IDEA and new project. I want to see the whole project's class diagram. I searched, and [it says on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282141/how-to-build-project-wide-uml-diagram-in-intellij-idea) that I have to

> click `Diagrams` > `Show Diagram` (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+U). You will see your package in diagram editor.

but I only see one box for the whole module. But I want to see all classes, relationship between them etc. How do I do this?

[image]

I'm using the latest version of IDEA Ultimate: 2017.3

Comment: You can do one package at a time.  I don't think a single big UML diagram is that useful.

Answer (score 4):

When invoked on the whole Project - it builds the diagram for the modules, not for classes. To have the Java class diagram invoke [show diagram action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-diagram.html#d879935e47) on a specific package or if you want to see all the packages and classes in project invoke it on a module's [source root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-projects.html#folder-categories). To expand a package (show it's content), select it and invoke "Expand" (<kbd>E</kbd> default shortcut) action.